Puppeteer Scraper Not Accessing Connected Clients in Node.js Server
I am developing a web application using Node.js, Express, Puppeteer, and MongoDB. My goal is to create a scraper that sends real-time updates to connected clients via Server-Sent Events (SSE). However, I am encountering an issue where the scraper script does not correctly recognize the connected clients, even though the clients are connected to the server.
Project Structure:

server.js: Manages the Express server, client connections, and SSE.
notifyClients.js: Handles client connections using a Map object.
scraper.js: Runs Puppeteer to scrape data and notify clients.

notifyClients.js:
const clientResponses = new Map();

const loadClients = () => {
    const clients = Array.from(clientResponses.keys());
    console.log(`Loaded clients: ${JSON.stringify(clients)}`);
    return clients;
};

const notifyClients = (message) => {
    const clients = loadClients();
    console.log('Notifying clients');
    clients.forEach((clientId) => {
        const client = clientResponses.get(clientId);
        if (client) {
            try {
                console.log(`Sending message to client ${clientId}: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
                client.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(message)}\n\n`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to send message to client ${clientId}:`, error);
            }
        }
    });
};

const addClient = (res) => {
    const clientId = Date.now().toString(); // Generate a unique ID for the client
    clientResponses.set(clientId, res);
    console.log(`Client connected with ID ${clientId}, total clients: ${clientResponses.size}`);

    res.on('close', () => {
        clientResponses.delete(clientId);
        console.log(`Client with ID ${clientId} disconnected, total clients: ${clientResponses.size}`);
    });
};

const getClientCount = () => {
    const count = clientResponses.size;
    console.log(`Getting client count: ${count}`);
    return count;
};

module.exports = {
    notifyClients,
    addClient,
    getClientCount,
    clientResponses  // Export clientResponses for use in server.js
};

server.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const { addClient, notifyClients, getClientCount, clientResponses } = require('./src/hooks/notifyClients');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY || 'your_secret_key';

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Frontend URL
  credentials: true,
}));
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch((error) => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error));

// Other schema definitions and middlewares

// SSE endpoint to send updates to the client
app.get('/api/products/updates', (req, res) => {
  console.log('SSE endpoint hit');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  res.flushHeaders();

  addClient(res); // Use addClient to manage the client connections
});

app.get('/api/check-clients', (req, res) => {
  const clients = Array.from(clientResponses.keys());
  res.json({
    clientCount: clients.length,
    clients: clients.map((clientId, index) => `Client ${index + 1}: ${clientId}`)
  });
});

// Other routes and server startup code

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

scraper.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { notifyClients, getClientCount, clients } = require('../hooks/notifyClients');
const axios = require('axios');

dotenv.config();

// MongoDB connection and other configurations

// Add a helper function to wait until clients are connected
const waitForClients = async (timeout = 30000, interval = 1000) => {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout) {
    const clientCount = getClientCount();
    console.log(`Waiting for clients. Current client count: ${clientCount}`);
    console.log(`Current clients array: ${JSON.stringify(clients)}`); // Log the current clients array for debugging

    // Perform the HTTP request to check client count
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/check-clients');
      console.log(`HTTP request response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`HTTP request error: ${error.message}`);
    }

    if (clientCount > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
  }
  console.log('No clients connected within the timeout period.');
  return false;
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  try {
    // Other scraping logic

    console.log('Waiting for clients to connect...');
    const clientsConnected = await waitForClients();
    if (!clientsConnected) {
      console.log('No clients connected within the timeout period.');
      return;
    }

    // Proceed with scraping and notifying clients
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
})();

Logs:
Scraper Logs:
Waiting for clients. Current client count: 0
Current clients array: undefined
HTTP request response: {"clientCount":2,"clients":["Client 1: 1719764974304","Client 2: 1719764991201"]}
Getting client count: 0

Server Logs:
Server is running on port 5000
SSE endpoint hit
Client connected with ID 1719764974304, total clients: 1
MongoDB Connected


Client Logs:
Setting up EventSource connection
EventSource connection established


What I Tried:

Verified that clients are correctly added to clientResponses in notifyClients.js.
Added logging in server.js and scraper.js to debug the client connection status.
Ensured that the clientResponses map is correctly imported and used in both server.js and scraper.js.
Expected Behavior:

The scraper should recognize the connected clients and send updates to them.
Actual Behavior:
The scraper does not recognize any connected clients and logs a client count of 0.
Question:
How can I ensure that the scraper script correctly recognizes and interacts with the connected clients managed by the server?

Why is Puppeteer making a request to the server, when it's already running on the server? Is it a different microservice? If so, how does it "respond" to the clients or send data back to the main server? The design here is pretty confusing--there should be a simple way to do this. Date.now().toString() is not a reliable unique ID. Use crypto.randomUUID().

The problem was as @ggorlen commented. It was running on 2 different servers and couldn't share the data. I moved it inside my server.js and now it works. Also I changed the ID generation to crypto.randomUUID as mentioned.
